# Using Google Calendar API as a "Events Database"

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

For a calendar app, I want to sync users calendars (events) to my database. For now, I need title, start, end, recurrence and reminders/alerts. I am thinking, I will get these information from app and store it to a database. To make things easy (implementing recurrence maybe hard), I thought of using a hidden Google Calendar account on the server as a database.

- Server will use a "hidden" Google Calendar account
- App (iOS) will get calendar information from user's iCal via EventKit
- Passes server this information which is saved to Google Calendar

  - So 1 user calendar becomes 1 hidden google calendar

But I think I might encounter some problems with API limits?

- I might need to re-authenticate to refresh the access token? Is there a token I do not have to refresh?
- Is the limit on the number of calendar I can have 10,000? What if I need more? Isit even possible? Or is it 10,000 for "a short period of time".

Is this possible? Or is the only option a self build system.

Answer (score 0):

The quota for the Google calendar API is Queries per day 1,000,000 if you go over that you can always request additional quota as far as I know it doesn't cost anything to extend your quota.

Once you have authentication to a user Google calendar account you will receive a refresh token. The refresh token can be used to gain a new access token when ever you need to access it.    Refresh tokens don't expire unless a user removes your access.